# substract functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, partial-fractions

Im trying to substract a set of functions
$$f(x)-g(x)-h(x)-i(x)$$

where
$$  f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+3)(x+4)^2(x+5)^3} $$
$$  g(x)=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{(x+5)^3} $$
$$  h(x)=\frac{-1}{(x+4)^2} $$
$$  i(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{(x+3)} $$

I use the common denominator approach

$$\frac{1}{(x+3)(x+4)^2(x+5)^3}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{(x+5)^3}+\frac{1}{(x+4)^2}-\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{(x+3)}=$$

$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}(x+3)(x+4)^2+(x+3)(x+5)^3-\frac{1}{8}(x+4)^2(x+5)^3}{(x+3)(x+4)^2(x+5)^3}$$
but how can be reduced this?; it is supposed to yield 
$$g(x)=\frac{20-3x-x^2}{8(x+4)(x+5)^2}$$

Thanks in advance
Update> making the products
$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}(x^3+11x^2+40x+48)+(x^4+18x^3+120x^2+350x+375)-\frac{1}{2}(x^5+23x^4+211x^3+965x^2+2200x+2000)}{(x+3)(x+4)^2(x+5)^3}$$
 and multiplying by 8

$$\frac{8+(4x^3+44x^2+160x+192)+(4x^4+72x^3+480x^2+1400x+1500)-(x^5+23x^4+211x^3+965x^2+2200x+2000)}{8(x+3)(x+4)^2(x+5)^3}$$
$$\frac{-x^5-19x^4-135x^3-441x^2-640x-300}{8(x+3)(x+4)^2(x+5)^3}$$
but still, this doesnt look too much like the $g(x)$; how can simplify the expression?

Comment: You need to develop carefully all the powers and products... For instance : $\frac 1 2 (x+3)(x+4)^2 = \frac 1 2 (x+3)(x^2+8x+16) = \frac 1 2(x^3+11x^2 +40x + 48)$ and so on... Good luck !

Comment: Note it will ease things a bit if you multiply the top and bottom by $8$. That will clear the fractions that appear in the top, and will also account for the $8$ you see in the denominator of the answer.

Comment: Knowing what the answer is supposed to be tells you that, when multiplied out, the numerator must be divisible by $(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)$ since the denominator is reduced by that amount.

Comment: ok, thanks! =) I have grasped the idea, sometimes you are too close and dont get the whole picture. Im doing the numbers and closing or edit the questions.